# Mixed results of the intersection of a line with a polygon in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, st-intersects

I have a line network and a some buffers. I would like to obtain the value of the buffers that the line intersects; however, I am getting mixed results that I am unsure how to interpret and solve the problem.

In the first case I run the following sql query to obtain the attribute value of each buffer ring/polygon:

```
<< Intersected line segments of buffer >>
CREATE TEMP TABLE intersected AS
     SELECT s.vul, 
      ST_Intersection(p.geom, s.geom) AS geom       -- intersected line inside buffers
      FROM
        public.line p,
        public.stream_buffer s;

-- << Intersected line segments outside of buffer >>
CREATE TEMP TABLE inter_nonbuffer AS 
      SELECT ST_Difference(l.geom, ST_Union(p.geom)) AS geom 
      FROM 
      public.line AS l
      JOIN public.stream_buffer AS p ON
      ST_Intersects (l.geom, p.geom)
      GROUP BY l.geom;

ALTER TABLE inter_nonbuffer     -- add vulnerability values of line segments outside buffer
ADD COLUMN vul float8;                      
UPDATE inter_nonbuffer
SET vul = 0.0; 

-- << Non-Intersected line sections >>
CREATE TEMP TABLE non_intersect AS
SELECT 
  p.id, p.geom, s.vul  
FROM 
  public.line AS p 
LEFT JOIN
  public.stream_buffer AS s ON
  ST_Intersects(p.geom,s.geom)
WHERE s.id IS NULL;

UPDATE non_intersect    -- insert vulnerability values of line segments outside buffer that 
SET vul=0.0             -- don't intersect.
WHERE vul IS NULL;

CREATE TABLE public.strm_vul AS                     -- create final vulnerability table
SELECT i.geom, i.vul FROM intersected i
UNION
SELECT ni.geom, ni.vul FROM inter_nonbuffer ni  
UNION
SELECT nb.geom, nb.vul FROM non_intersect nb;

ALTER TABLE public.strm_vul ADD COLUMN id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY;       -- add id column
```

[image: Case 1]
Above: Case1.

In the second case my buffer polygons are nowhere near my line network and I try the same approach, but only run the << Intersected line segments of buffer >> section of the query and it returns 16 000 + 'vul' values.  I should receive zero entries because nothing should have been intersected:

```
<< Intersected line segments of buffer >>
    CREATE TEMP TABLE intersected AS
         SELECT s.vul, 
          ST_Intersection(p.geom, s.geom) AS geom       -- intersected line inside buffers
          FROM
            public.line p,
            public.other_buffer s;
```

[image: Case 2]
Above: Case 2